# How to find row using multiple condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a getData method and I am unable to get row using multiple conditions.
because I am trying to set input value where rows condition is matched. but it's not working yet

```
function getData() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: APIUrl + 'api/GetCustomerProductDetailsDetailByEmployeeID?JSONStringData=' + JSON.stringify(objReqCustomerProductDetails),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            objResCustomerProductDetails = data;

            if ($(objResCustomerProductDetails.CustomerProductDetails).length > 0) {

                $.each(objResCustomerProductDetails.CustomerProductDetails, function () {

                    $('#tbCustomer tbody tr[data-id=' + this.CustomerID + ' data-product-id=' + this.ProductID + '] td').find('input').val(parseFloat(this.Quantity.toString().trim()).toFixed(2));

                });
            }

        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            messageProvider(0, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#tbCustomer tbody tr[data-id=' + this.CustomerID + '][data-product-id=' + this.ProductID + '] td').find('input').val(parseFloat(this.Quantity.toString().trim()).toFixed(2));
```

After an attribute ends you need to close it. Convention is `[attr1][attr2]`. This was the problem with the above code.

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: I know about it. but it's taking 5 minutes.